# Could you use Twincast to counter Cryptic Command?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If your opponent casts [Cryptic Command](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=438614) to tap all your creatures and draw a card, can you use [Twincast](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bTwincast%5d) to counter it and draw a card?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the Twincast's rulings:

> If the spell Twincast copies is modal (that is, it says “Choose one —” or the like), the copy will have the same mode. You can’t choose a different one.

From Comprehensive Rules (thanks [ikegami](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/users/2880/ikegami)):

> 706.2. When copying an object, the copy acquires the copiable values of the original object’s characteristics and, **for an object on the stack, choices made when casting or activating it (mode**, targets, the value of X, whether it was kicked, how it will affect multiple targets, and so on). [...]

(Emphasis mine.)

So, no.
Twincast has the same modes that your opponent chose. If they chose *tap and draw*, Twincast will also *tap and draw*.

Comment: I should have checked both the cards gatherer text before posting.