# Choose new modes for a copy

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Can I choose new modes when I copy a spell whith modes.
For example, I copy a [Cryptic Command](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Cryptic%20Command) with a [Reverberate](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Reverberate), can I choose new modes for my copy of Cryptic Command?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could you use Twincast to counter Cryptic Command?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/41805/could-you-use-twincast-to-counter-cryptic-command)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**No, when you copy a spell, you also copy all choices made for the original.**

> 707.2. When copying an object, the copy acquires the copiable values of the original object’s characteristics and, for an object on the stack, choices made when casting or activating it (mode, targets, the value of X, whether it was kicked, how it will affect multiple targets, and so on). [..]

Of course, this does not include choices you make on resolution, for example when you copy [Akroma's Blessing](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Akroma%27s%20Blessing). But Cryptic Command's choice is a choice of modes, so the copy will have the same modes and you only get to choose new targets if you want.

Comment: How is Akroma's Blessing different from Cryptic Command? Why is "choose a color" different to "choose two:"?

Comment: The wording is different. The former simply happens as part of resolution, the latter is defined in the rules as part of the casting process and thus copiable. I will edit my answer to include the relevant rules refs.

Comment: @nick012000 I'll answer as comment because it's not really relevant to the question, since OP knows what a mode is: *700.2. A spell or ability is modal if it has two or more options in a bulleted list preceded by instructions for a player to choose a number of those options, such as “Choose one —.”* If the wording doesn't conform to this definition, it's not a mode and thus part of the resolution.

Comment: So "choose two" is modal and choice is copied but "choose one" is not modal and the choice can done at resolution? :/

Comment: @sinsedrix that is not correct. Both are modal. "two or more options" refers to the number of options in the bulleted list. The instruction for how many to choose from that list can be variable.